# How to convert .net DateTime to SQL Server DateTime2

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I want to insert DateTime variable into database table column of DateTime2 type (from .net program)
(im using sqlServer 2008, .net 4.0, c#)

now I have

```
     string insertCommand = @"INSERT INTO X VALUES (time.ToString());
```

Problem is in time string format. SQL Server does not work with output from ToString() function. I also tried .ToLongDate short date etc..
How to create proper sql command and how to format dateTime string to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string sql = "insert into x values (@dt)";
SqlCommand cmd = cxn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", time);
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Considering time as datetime of C#, when I do the same, only the date is stored in the database and not the timestamp. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a parameter with your `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 0):

not confirm but you can use use format times.tostring("dd/MMM/yyyy")
like
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx